# How to register service at UWP project

Tags: xamarin, uwp

I am trying to register alert service ( message dialog) at setup.cs for this method

```
   protected override void InitializePlatformServices() {
            base.InitializePlatformServices();
            Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IAlertService>(new AlertService());
        }
```

but i also have this exception http://prntscr.com/krpbcw

Answer (score 1):

For services which has implementation in native projects.
Go to Setup.cs

```
protected override IMvxApplication CreateApp(){
            Mvx.RegisterType< IAlertService, AlertService >();

}
```

Know one thing, AlertService implements IAlertService